# How can i increase the height of Unicode symbol

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the height of this symbol "│" in a span like

`<span>│</span>`

I already tried to increase the font-size but it also increase the width of the symbol.

I need it for render a dynamic diagram.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Hello @Toothgip, Welcome to stackoverflow, Try using font-size or transform:scale to span to increase size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css scale.
In my experience, it will blur things a bit, but it's the only way I think you can change the size of your pipe symbol.

Personally I would just draw a vertical line in css.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(1, 3);
}
```

```html
original: |
scaled: <span>|</span>
```